# Populate input data-source options from on page div content with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to populate the data-source list of the input dynamically with the content of the "location" div using jQuery. I am using Bootstrap typeahead which is working nicely but I would like to make the data-source list dynamic.

Here is the code

```
<input
    data-path=".location"
    type="text"
    value=""
    id="location-filter"
    placeholder="Filter By Location ie. New York"
    data-control-type="textbox"
    data-control-name="desc-filter"
    data-control-action="filter"
    data-provide="typeahead"
    data-items="4" 
    data-source='["New York","Los Angeles","Chicago"]'
/>


<div class="block">
    <div class="type">Administration</div>
    <div class="desc">School Administrator</div>
    <div class="company">Administration Services LLC</div>
    <div class="location">New York</div>
    <div class="date">November 23</div>
</div><!--/block-->

<div class="block">
    <div class="type">Construction</div>
    <div class="desc">Roofing Contractor</div>
    <div class="company">Raise The Roof Inc.</div>
    <div class="location">Chicago</div>
    <div class="date">November 24</div>
</div><!--/block-->

<div class="block">
    <div class="type">Designer</div>
    <div class="desc">Web Designer</div>
    <div class="company">Web Designz Inc.</div>
    <div class="location">Los Angeles</div>
    <div class="date">November 25</div>
</div><!--/block-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by retrieving all the text fields from divs that have `class="location"`:

```
$(function () {
    var category_array = $(".location").map(function() {
                         return $(this).text();
                     }).get();

    var autocomplete = $('#location-filter').typeahead({source: category_array}); 
});
```

To remove duplicates from the array:

```
$(function () {
    var category_array = $(".location").map(function() {
                         return $(this).text();
                     }).get();

    // Remove duplicates
    // Note - this assumes the exact same string (including uppercase/lowercase) 
    category_array = $.grep(category_array, function(v, k){
                return $.inArray(v, category_array) === k;
          });

    var autocomplete = $('#location-filter').typeahead({source: category_array}); 
});
```

See here for a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/3C6rT/8/).

Comment: This is perfect. Is there a way to limit the occurrences of the location in the list? IT will be likely I will have multiple listings of the same location. YOu are the man.